# When HDD wakes up?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, electrical-power

Im looking for some small script or application which could log the time when a non-system disk wakes up.

I cannot identify which application or script wakes up my non-system drive (which has to be asleep until I work with it). I have already set the noatime flag, tried to use powertop and iotop to determine which application could prevent it from going to sleep - but with no result.

So my plan is to set this drive asleep (hdparm -Y) and see at what time it gets regularly woken up.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find out what files are being accessed (which may help narrow down the process responsible), you can try using [`inotifywatch`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#info) which can be set up to recursively watch directories below a directory you choose. Be sure to read the warnings in the man page regarding using `--recursive` on a large tree.

When a filesystem event occurs in a directory in that tree, it is recorded and output in a table. You can use `--timeout` to limit the amount of time that the watch is active.

If the results are consistent, you can run a non-recursive watch on the files in that directory to narrow down the particular file.

Answer (score 3):

As you are on linux, you can use the new `fatrace` utility, which logs every file access and tells you which process is responsible:

https://launchpad.net/fatrace

More information here:

http://www.piware.de/2012/02/fatrace-report-system-wide-file-access-events/

It makes use of the [linux fanotify API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) ([more details](http://lwn.net/Articles/360955/)) available since linux kernel 2.6.37.

`fatrace` isn't packaged by most distributions as of July 2014 (it entered debian testing recently, so should ship in 'jessie'), but is easy to install from source.

Answer (score 2):

See this ubuntu [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/638765) on how to track that down (and a possible cause).

Short answers: `auditctl -w /dev/sdX -p rwa` and udisks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hdparm -C` to get the power mode status of the disk at any time. Here's a script that would give you the times:

```
while true; do 
  state=`hdparm -C /dev/sda|grep "^ drive"|cut -c 19-`
  echo `date` $state
  sleep 1
done
```

Run the script with `sudo`, as `hdparm` needs root privileges. You can redirect echo to some file, e.g.:

```
echo `date` $state >> /tmp/sda_state
```

and of course change the disk you are monitoring (I used `/dev/sda`) to what you want and the `sleep` interval, such as `sleep 120` to query every two minutes.

This doesn't give you the process which wakes up the drive, though.

You may have issues with the above due to some bugs:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=507963

If you are having issues with `hdparm -C` waking up your drive, try this instead:

```
smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sda|grep "^Power mode"
```

As per `man smartctl`, when run with `-n standby`, `smartctl` should not wake up the drive. Note there are also bugs with this:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smartmontools/+bug/497256

so try to see if it works.

Comment: hdparm -C wakes up the drive as well

Comment: I edited to provide an alternative - hope this is going to work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the drive still wakes up, I even tried the new version of smartmontools 5.40 but with no result :( Anyway thanks for your advice!

Comment: Try trying the latest version of `hdparm` also. Sorry it didn't work out for you, but it very well might be an issue with the hardware. If you can, try it on some other machine and/or a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer to your question but I want to point on you on a detail that might be interesting: several sata hdd have a jumper to set them sleeping by default (the controller has to send a sata command to wake up the disk. [not all controllers can do that]).

Is the jumper already set?

Dam

Comment: I looked into the manual for Seagate drives, but it appears to have only one possible jumper configuration and that's to limit the drive's operation to 1.5Gbps.

Comment: what's the model and sn# of the disk?

Comment: Barracuda,3QD0CGGM

Comment: mmm can't find anything helpfull about the spin-down of that disk. Sorry